# Setting `backgroundColor` in style hides `View` component

Tags: react-native

I have the following `render()` function in my component, it is replicating the look and feel of a table, but using flex in react-native.

```
<View>
    <View key={ 'test' } style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
            <Text>Col1</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
            <Text>Col2</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
            <Text>Col3</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
            <Text>Col4</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
            <Text>Col5</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
```

Which renders perfectly fine and as expected. However if I add `backgroundColor: 'green'` into the style of the top-most-level view, above, then the whole view is just gone. Can't even see it in the react-native inspector anymore.

Any idea why this is happening? Am I missing some gotcha, to do with not using background colors on nested `View` or something?

**Edit**: It is because there was a  being wrapped around my component from the parent component, which also had to have `flex: 1` explicitly set. Not sure why only adding `backgroundColor` causes this but there we go.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue : https://snack.expo.io/SyMGvUBlX

Comment: @sanjar - Turns out it's because I had an extra `View` component as a parent that didn't explicitly set `flex: 1`. I have updated the question with the actual component and as you can see using your snack, it doesn't render. However I think that is user error as opposed to a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the style of the first view to `flex: 1`

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View key={ 'test' } style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
            <Text>Col1</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
            <Text>Col2</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
            <Text>Col3</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
            <Text>Col4</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
            <Text>Col5</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, I think by setting the height and width to your parent view solve the problem

```
<View key={ 'test' } style={{ height: 500, width:500, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
            <Text>Col1</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
            <Text>Col2</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
            <Text>Col3</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
            <Text>Col4</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
            <Text>Col5</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
```